how to convert for each loop into lambda for each?
I have the code below where I take an array of string and I convert to an array of char.
How can I transform it so i use the lambda function?
I have a function (countOcc) which requires a char array (char[][]), but I wanted to make it possible to use it with a string array (String[]) using the method toArray of a string.
public final int countOcc (String[] value) {
    int m = 1;
    for (String v : value) if (v.length() >= m) m = v.length();
    char[][] a = new char[value.length][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) a[i] = value[i].toCharArray();
    return countOcc(a);
 }

i tried using Arrays.stream().foreach() like below but when i do things like c++ it gives me an error
public final int countOcc (String[] value) {
    int m = 1;
    Arrays.stream(value).forEach(e -> {
        if (e.length() >= m) m = e.length();
    });
    char[][] a = new char[value.length][m];
    int c = 0;
    Arrays.stream(value).forEach(e -> {
        a[c] = e.toCharArray();
        c++;
    });
    return countOcc(a);
}


What is the objective of the code you're writing?

i have a function (countOcc) which requires a char array (char[][]) but i wanted to make possible to use it with a string array(String[]) using the method toArray of a string @g00se

I suspect you want character frequency counts, so: Map<String, Long> counts = Arrays.stream(args).flatMapToInt(String::codePoints).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));System.out.println(counts);

Note particularly that the bounds of char have been inadequate for a long time and everything should be oriented to codepoints (int) nowadays. So, the 'characters' end up as Strings, as they should, in the keys of the Map in my example

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your error tells you that inside your lambda you are not allowed to change a variable that exists outside the lambda (it probably says the variable has to be "effectively final"). You could help us be sure when you paste the error message into your question. So c++ doesn’t go. As an aside when supplying the inner arrays later, also allocating them from the start is just a waste. So in your working code delete the first for-each loop and allocate the array with just char[][] a = new char[value.length][]; leaving out the m.

If you are trying to convert a String[] to a char[][] then do something like:
String[] value = {"foo", "bar", "fizz"};
char[][] a = Arrays.stream(value).map(s -> s.toCharArray()).toArray(char[][]::new);

then call your other method
return countOcc(a);


It is always best to read the official documentation. But as an introduction you can read this article from oracle. Baeldung is also a good website with easy explanations and examples. Here an introduction and some follow ups

BTW s -> s.toCharArray() can be replaced by String::toCharArray (at least to be consistent with char[][]::new)

I suspect you want character frequency counts, so you can use streaming and Collectors to achieve that.
Note particularly that the bounds of char have been inadequate for a long time and everything should be oriented to codepoints (int) nowadays. So, the 'characters' end up as Strings, as they should, in the keys of the Map in the example below.
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CharacterFrequencyCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String flag = new String(new int[] { 0x1F1EC, 0x1F1E7 }, 0, 2);
        String[] text = new String[] {
                "This is the flag of Great Britain",
                flag };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(text));
        System.out.println(CharacterFrequencyCounter.getCounts(text));

    }

    public static Map<String, Long> getCounts(String... strings) {
        return Arrays.stream(strings).flatMapToInt(String::codePoints).mapToObj(Character::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    }
}

